# Object data Separate Uniqe wise Value in Javascruipt

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have Object List Data.
I have to sort wise uniqueid by value. and their data store respective uniqueid Object.
** Object List **

```
{
 uniqueid : 200,
 name : "sandesh",
 loop: 222,
 salary : 2500
},
{
 uniqueid : 300,
 name : "hello",
 loop: 222,
 salary : 2500
},
{
 uniqueid : 300,
 name : "hello1",
 loop: 222,
 salary : 2500
};
```

I will create an object uniqueid  wise and Store there value but every data create duplicate object.

```
var newArray = [];
    this.userBetHistory.forEach(item => {
       var newItem = {uniqueid : item.uniqueid, BetData: []};
       this.userBetHistory.forEach(innerItem => {
          if(innerItem.uniqueid== item.uniqueid){           
              newItem.BetData = newItem.BetData.concat(innerItem);
          }
       });
      newArray.push(newItem);
    });
```

** Expected Output: **

```
{
 uniqueid : 200,
 data : 
     {
      uniqueid : 200,
      name : "sandesh",
      loop: 222,
      salary : 2500
     }
},
{
 uniqueid : 300,
 data : 
      {
        uniqueid : 300,
        name : "hello",
        loop: 222,
        salary : 2500
      },
      {
        uniqueid : 300,
        name : "hello1",
        loop: 222,
        salary : 2500
      }
}
```

Comment: Expected output is not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for formatting the data

```js
let data = [{uniqueid:200,name:'sandesh',loop:222,salary:2500,},{uniqueid:300,name:'hello',loop:222,salary:2500,},{uniqueid:300,name:'hello1',loop:222,salary:2500,},]

const formattedData = (data) => {
  const result = data.reduce((res, d) => {
    if(res[d.uniqueid]) {
      res[d.uniqueid].data.push(d);
    } else {
      res[d.uniqueid] = {
        uniqueid: d.uniqueid,
        data: [
          {...d}
        ]
      }
    }
    return res;
  }, {}) ;
  return Object.values(result);
}

console.log(formattedData(data))
```

Hope this is what the output that you are looking for

Comment: Work this Solution. Thanks @Nithish

Comment: Glad to have helped you @SandeshMankar.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with some mapping and filtering.

```js
const userBetHistory = [{uniqueid: 200,name: "sandesh",loop: 222,salary: 2500,},{uniqueid: 300,name: "hello",loop: 222,salary: 2500,},{uniqueid: 300,name: "hello1",loop: 222,salary: 2500, }];

let tempData = userBetHistory.map((activeBet) => {
  const activeBetSubData = userBetHistory.filter(
    (bet) => bet.uniqueid === activeBet.uniqueid
  );
  return {
    uniqueid: activeBetSubData[0].uniqueid,
    data: activeBetSubData,
  };
});

tempData = tempData
  .map((item) => item.uniqueid)
  .map((item, i, final) => final.indexOf(item) === i && i)
  .filter((item) => tempData[item])
  .map((item) => tempData[item]);

console.log(tempData);
```